# Accessing Data sets from Json

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am mapping JSON data to my own classes in C# and then trying to display various data where I need it however I'm having a small issue where I can't seem to get at data when I believe I should be able to. Obviously something is wrong and I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction:

Example snippet of JSON:

```
"items"
{       
    "0"
    {
        "name"      "Riki's Dagger"
        "prefab"        "default_item"
        "item_name"     "#DOTA_Item_Rikis_Dagger"
        "item_type_name"        "#DOTA_WearableType_Daggers"
        "model_player"      "models/heroes/rikimaru/rikimaru_weapon.mdl"
        "used_by_heroes"
        {
            "npc_dota_hero_riki"        "1"
        }
    }
    "1"
    {
        "name"      "Anti-Mage's Glaive"
        "prefab"        "default_item"
        "item_description"      "#DOTA_Item_Desc_AntiMages_Glaives"
        "item_name"     "#DOTA_Item_AntiMages_Glaive"
        "item_type_name"        "#DOTA_WearableType_Glaive"
        "model_player"      "models/heroes/antimage/antimage_weapon.mdl"
        "used_by_heroes"
        {
            "npc_dota_hero_antimage"        "1"
        }
}
```

I am using the following to serialize this to my own classes as follows:

```
DotaItemsGameResult itemGameResult
    = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DotaItemsGameResult>(rawItemDetailsJson);
```

This is working OK as I have used this elsewhere.

The trouble comes here:

```
string dataToDisplay = "";

foreach (DotaItemsGameItem item in itemGameResult.Items_Game.Items.Item_Index)
{
    dataToDisplay += "<h3> Item: " + item.Name + "</h3>";                 
    dataToDisplay += "<p> Quality: " + item.Item_Quality + "</p>";
    dataToDisplay += "<p> Attributes: " + item.Used_By_Heroes + "</p>";
}

return dataToDisplay;
```

My code seems to know about `itemGameResult.Items_Game.Items` but not when I want to go further into `.Items_Index`.

I have the following classes:

```
public class DotaItemsGameResult
{
    public DotaItemsGameResultProperties Items_Game { get; set; }
}

public class DotaItemsGameResultProperties
{
    public List<DotaItemsGameRarities> Rarities { get; set; }
    public List<DotaItemsGameItems> Items { get; set; }
}

public class DotaItemsGameItems
{
    public List<DotaItemsGameItem> Item_Index { get; set; }
}

public class DotaItemsGameItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Hidden { get; set; }
    public string Item_Class { get; set; }
    public string Item_Name { get; set; }
    public string Item_Slot { get; set; }
    public string Item_Quality { get; set; }
    public string Min_Ilevel { get; set; }
    public string Max_Ilevel { get; set; }
    public string Item_Description { get; set; }
    public string Item_Type_Name { get; set; }
    public List<DotaItemsGameUsedByHero> Used_By_Heroes { get; set; }        
}
```

Basically, my aim is to be able to get at the `Used_By_Heroes` data in my loop but I can't.

In my for each, `itemGameResult.Items_Game.Items` is fine, but `itemGameResult.Items_Game.Items.Item_Index` is not and I can't see why.

I can't access the the `Item_Index` when I use dot notation, there's no `Item_Index` where I would expect there to be. If I put it in anyway and try to compile, I see this:

> Error 1   'System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a definition for 'Item_Index' and no extension method 'Item_Index' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Any help would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that the `Items` property of the class `DotaItemsGameResultProperties` is a collection (`List<DotaItemsGameItems>`) so it doesn't have a property `Item_Index`. Not sure what do you want to achieve, but one possibility to fix this is to iterate on this collection also:

```
string dataToDisplay = "";

foreach (DotaItemsGameItems items in itemGameResult.Items_Game.Items)
{
    foreach (DotaItemsGameItem item in items.Item_Index)
    {
        dataToDisplay += "<h3> Item: " + item.Name + "</h3>";                 
        dataToDisplay += "<p> Quality: " + item.Item_Quality + "</p>";
        dataToDisplay += "<p> Attributes: " + item.Used_By_Heroes + "</p>";
    }
}

return dataToDisplay;
```

This is to illustrate the structure of your data, you can do this in a more concise way:

```
string dataToDisplay = "";

var allItems = itemGameResult.Items_Game.Items.SelectMany(i => i.Item_Index);
foreach (DotaItemsGameItem item in allItems)
{
    dataToDisplay += "<h3> Item: " + item.Name + "</h3>";                 
    dataToDisplay += "<p> Quality: " + item.Item_Quality + "</p>";
    dataToDisplay += "<p> Attributes: " + item.Used_By_Heroes + "</p>";
}

return dataToDisplay;
```